# AutoCAD 2013 - Error: ARXLOAD failed

Tags: autocad, objectarx

currently i have autocad 2012 and want to upgrade to autocad 2013.

I have a custom made addition to my autocad.
But when i try to load this i get this:

COM.VLX loaded.; error: ARXLOAD failed

```
    Here is a part of my acaddoc.lsp:
    ;; ACADDOC.LSP is loaded into memory before the drawing is completely     
    ;; initialized. S::STARTUP is called when a new drawing or an existing    
    ;; drawing is opened. And is guaranteed to perform any setup operations   
    ;; after a drawing is initialized.                                        

    (defun LoadARXVBA(/ strplatform strExt)
      (if (wcmatch (getvar "platform") "*(x64)*")
        (setq strExt "x64.arx")
        (setq strExt ".arx")
      )  

             ;; load arx modules
             (arxload (strcat "DetectESC" strExt))
             (arxload (strcat "osnap" strExt))
             (arxload (strcat "beditReactor" strExt))
             ;; load vba projects
             (vla-loaddvb (acadobject) (findfile "sinkblock.dvb"))
             (vla-loaddvb (acadobject) (findfile "triggers.dvb"))
             (if (member "plotlog.arx" (arx));if loaded by acad.rx
                 (vla-loaddvb (acadobject) (findfile "PlotLog.dvb"))
             )   
             ;; connect to plotlog server
             (if (member (strcat "plotlog" strExt) (arx))
               (vla-runmacro (acadobject) "StartMonitor")
             )   
             ;; visuallisp projects
             (load "base.vlx")
             (load "startup.vlx")
         (load "TSLOAD"); Load TIMESAVERS' commands:
             (defun EVALCHK (dummy / ) 1)
             ;; run stuff
             (startup)
    )  


(defun-q    main(/)
    ;; load visuallisp & vba projects
    (setvar "screenmenu" 1) 
    (setvar "menubar" 1)    
    (load "com.vlx")
    (if (eq (vla-get-visible (acadobject)) :vlax-true)
      (LoadARXVBA)

    ) ;end if
    (princ)
) ;end main

(setvar "savetime" 8) 



;; append 'main function to any posible existing S::STARTUP function
(setq s::startup (append s::startup main))
;|«Visual LISP© Format Options»
(100 2 1 2 nil "end of " 100 70 0 0 nil T T nil T)
;*** DO NOT add text below the comment! ***|;
```

Can anyone help me with this?
I have read at some places that there something changed in the arx loading ...

Answer (score 0):

The ARX module will need to be rebuilt with the ObjectARX 2013 SDK for use in AutoCAD 2013.

Comment: Owen, and for this i probably need the origional files ... Or is there a other way?

Comment: Yes, you need the source code, either the original or write it again.

Answer (score 0):

Download ObjectARX 2013 : http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=785550 and rebuild your solution using the 2013 SDK.

Here is the ObjectARX Wizard for AutoCAD 2013 and MSVC 2010 : http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=785550

Hope it helped.

Tom,